# Где ошибка в коде? Не работает

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function seeaboutme() {
  display = document.getElementById("aboutme").style.display;

  if (display == "none") {
    document.getElementById(aboutme).style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(aboutme).style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```css
#aboutme {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="menulinks" onclick="seeaboutme()">About me</a><br>

<a id="aboutme">Hello everybody</a>
```

Как при нажатии на кнопку **About me** (который изначально скрыт) сделать чтобы появлялся текст?

Comment: Код пытается обращаться к переменной aboutme, но такой переменной не существует

Comment: а почему закрыть? оформить и оставить.

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли кавычки добавить `document.getElementById(aboutme)` в условиях:

```js
function seeaboutme(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var el = document.getElementById("aboutme");
  var display = el.style.display;


  if (display === "none") {
    el.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    el.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```css
#aboutme {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="menulinks" onclick="seeaboutme(event)">About me</a>

<br>

<a href="#" id="aboutme">Hello everybody</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для получения текущего значения CSS свойства надо использовать [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

```js
function seeaboutme(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var el = document.getElementById("aboutme");
  var display = getComputedStyle(el).display;

  if (display === "none") {
    el.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    el.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```css
#aboutme {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="menulinks" onclick="seeaboutme(event)">About me</a>

<br>

<a href="#" id="aboutme">Hello everybody</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> display = document.getElementById("aboutme").style.display;
> ```

```
var display = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("aboutme")).display;
```